# How to reference current http context when using HttpListener?

Tags: vb.net, httplistener

When using ASP we can reference HttpContext.Current from anywhere in the code to get at the current http context.

I want to do something similar using HttpListener, so that I can access GET/POST data etc from anywhere in my code. Can I reference some global object for this, or do I need to explicitly pass the current HttpListenerContext object all through my code?

```
' This is what I want to access
Dim Context As HttpListenerContext = Listener.EndGetContext(StateObject)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ok so no bites, but I solved it myself. I found two ways of doing this:**

1) Store the httplistener request context in Thread Storage - works, but theres an easier way;

2) Store the httplistener request context in a ThreadStatic variable - too easy!

```
Public Class CurrentRequest

    <ThreadStatic()> Public Shared QueryString As String
    <ThreadStatic()> Public Shared PostStream As Stream

End Class
```

Comment: This is not correct. 'PerThread' cannot guarantee correctness in a web app based on ThreadPool and Http uses ThreadPool. Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845898/castle-windsor-perthread-vs-perwebrequest-in-asp-net

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the context object as argument through your code to allow for better multithreading. Statics will lead to corruption (when you do not have the proper context as pointed by Tymek, or if not properly protected by synchronization), or to concurrency issues. By passing the context object you allow for as many requests as necessary to execute in parallel.